# How to remove all inactive CI_Session?

Tags: codeigniter

Currently, I am saving all CI_Session data in AWS RDS (MySQL) and the number of rows in CI_Session table exceeded over 1,300,000.

I want to sort out all inactive CI_Session, so that I can effectively manage CI_Session table. How do I do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you create a cron-job or write a function to clear all inactive session,when a user logs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

```
$this->db->query('DELETE FROM ci_sessions  WHERE  timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR');

$this->db->query('OPTIMIZE TABLE ci_sessions');
```

Comment: If not changed in `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` interval should be more or equal than 7200 seconds or two hours.